# Find $\lim_\limits{x\to 1}{x^\alpha-1\over x^\beta -1}$. What has gone wrong?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Find $\lim_\limits{x\to 1}{x^\alpha-1\over x^\beta -1}$. 
Using L'Hopital's rule I get that $$\lim_\limits{x\to 1}{x^\alpha-1\over x^\beta -1}=\lim_\limits{x\to 1}{\alpha x^{\alpha-1}\over \beta x^{\beta -1}}={\alpha\over \beta}$$ but using it again, which should give me the same, I get $$\lim_\limits{x\to 1}{\alpha x^{\alpha-1}\over \beta x^{\beta -1}}=\lim_\limits{x\to 1}{(\alpha-1)\alpha x^{\alpha-2}\over (\beta -1)\beta x^{\beta -2}}={(\alpha -1)\alpha\over (\beta -1)\beta}??$$ (Not to mention using it again and again and again.)
I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use it again, since you no longer have an indeterminate case.

Comment: Oh
I forgot that fact. 
Is that because it is not of the form ${0\over 0}$ or ${\infty\over \infty}$?/

Comment: @Meitar Exactly.